# What does <qual> stand for in the FHS?

Tags: linux, fhs

The [Linux FHS (Filesystem Hierarchy Standard)](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) refers to directories of the following form:

```
/lib<qual>
```

It describes such directories as follows:

> There may be one or more variants of the /lib directory on systems which support more than one binary format requiring separate libraries.

Similarly, it refers to directories:

```
/usr/lib<qual>
```

And describes them as:

> /usr/lib performs the same role as /usr/lib for an alternate binary format, except that the symbolic links /usr/lib/sendmail and /usr/lib/X11 are not required.

The [FHS Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) gives the following alternate descriptions for these directories:

> `/lib<qual>`
>
> Alternate format essential libraries. Such directories are optional, but if they exist, they have some requirements.
>
> `/usr/lib<qual>`
>
> Alternate format libraries, e.g. /usr/lib32 for 32-bit libraries on a 64-bit machine (optional).

I'm assuming that the string `<qual>` is a mnemonic for something. Is it? If so, what does it represent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Qualifier"

> a word or phrase, especially an adjective, used to attribute a quality to another word, especially a noun.
>
> (in systemic grammar) a word or phrase added after a noun to qualify its meaning.

The strings `32` and `64` are qualifiers to the path `/usr/lib` that qualifies the path's use. With `32`, making it `/usr/lib32`, it denotes the specific path for 32-bit (only) libraries, as the quoted text says, on 64-bit machines.

---

As Stephen Kitt points out in comments below, other qualifiers than just "the number of bits on an architecture" may be found on some systems, especially on MIPS systems.

Comment: +1. It might be worth pointing out that 32 and 64 aren’t the only qualifiers, MIPS for example has many more; but their purpose is always the same.

Comment: That makes sense. Are there any other qualifiers besides the ones that specify the machine architecture?

Comment: @StephenKitt Yeah, that's what I found confusing. I would have found `lib<bits>` (or something like that) to be more intuitive.

Comment: @igal it’s always related to the machine architecture (or rather, the ABI supported by the binaries contained in the `lib<qual>` directory). Examples include `x32` (for the `x32` x86 ABI), `n32` (some MIPS variant) etc. If you’re particularly curious you might enjoy the discussion of the various issues in [this thread on Debian multi-arch](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2004/01/msg00762.html).